# Discover mobile devices (Android and IOS) using .NET

Tags: android, .net, ios, networking, discovery

I am working on an ASP.NET (VB.NET) application which will discover devices connected on network. Is there a way through which i can discover IOS devices (iphone, ipad, ipod) and android devices (phones, tablets) connected to my network?

Please assist.

Thanks.

Umer

Answer (score 0):

Most iOS devices support bonjour service discovery (same as Avahi or ZeroConf). You can discover nodes in the local network that will answer to your requests (by default most iDevices).

I guess wikipedia is a good starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking#Service_discovery.

I'm not sure how it can be done in .NET but you can try http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf.